# How can I disable windows forcing me to update to 8.1?

Tags: windows-8

Ever since I have bought windows 8, I have had stupid notifications of

> Do you want to update to windows 8.1

That was fine.

But now for some reason, it says "Finish updating to windows 8.1, your PC will be restarting in X hours to start installation". There is no cancel button, it only selects a time to install (up to 4 hours from now), and to avoid clicking install I have to restart the computer. Which is horribly frustrating.

I would love to get a screenshot, but when it comes up everything else is blocked and non-useable.

How can I disable these forced-update things?

Comment: First the upgrade to 8.1 is optional so at some point you confirmed you wanted to download the update. Why are you against installing an update that makes Windows 8 more usable?

Comment: Why would you not want to update? That message indicates that the update is already partially installed. You may run into problems in the future.

Comment: @rrirower Maybe because changing OS's resets all data on computers?

Comment: @Joehot200 - Since when?  Doing an upgrade to 8.1 allows you to keep EVERYTHING EXACTLY how you have it.  Its a 100% in-place upgrade.  You lose no personal files, application settings, or installed desktop programs

Comment: @Ramhound I keep hearing of the update process going wrong and people losing their files. I don't want to take a risk to fix a non-broken thing. Especially as I have years of work on my computer.

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/windows-updates-activation/53755-forced-upgrade-windows-8-1-a-3.html tells you how to stop it. There are several updates that need to be uninstalled and hidden.

Comment: @DavidPostill That crashed my computer and it would only start on the 6th try. And amusingly, the update that apparently causes this is still gone... So thanks!

Comment: @Joehot200 - If your files are so important you should consider doing a backup of your system.  Don't wait until something happens, and it will happen, only a matter of time.  Besides by staying on Windows 8 your stuck with a version of IE that is less secure and eventually you won't get critical updates because Windows 8 will be supported the very minimal amount of time due to the fact 8.1 is a free upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound Fair enough. I'll back them up to a hard disk (I could use google drive but my internet is so slow).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot cancel an scheduled automatic restart, but you can disable automatic restarts when you are logged on.
This work from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 :

In registry base, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows`.

Create a key named `WindowsUpdate` if needed.

In this key create a DWORD Value named `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` and set it to `1`.

From http://blog.laptopmag.com/disable-automatic-restart-windows

Comment: I would not recommend making registry changes manually without knowing the future implications.

Comment: @Dric - How about post the relevant information from your link?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but useful all the same.

Comment: @rrirower This only disable the automatic restart when a user is logged on, but the updates are installed when the computer is restarted. This doesn't break anything, and disabling automatic restart should be a system option.